# How to copy a ruby variable?

Tags: ruby, variables

Maybe I've just been staring at my screen too long today, but something I think should be very basic is stumping me.

I'm trying to make a 'copy' of a variable so I can manipulate it without modifying the original.

```
# original var is set
foo = ["a","b","c"]

# i want a copy of the original var so i dont modify the original
bar = foo

# modify the copied var
bar.delete("b")

# output the values
puts bar # outputs: ["a","c"] - this is right
puts foo # outputs: ["a","c"] - why is this also getting modified?
```

I want `foo` not to be changed.

Comment: You can't copy a variable. All you can do is copy the object that a variable refers to. This may sound pedantic, but not understanding the difference between an object and a variable can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`foo` and `bar` refer to the same object. To make `bar` refer to a different object, you have to clone `foo`:

```
bar = foo.clone
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the dup method:

```
bar = foo.dup
```

This will return a copy of foo, so any changes you make to bar will not effect foo.

Answer (score 3):

In the below code you can see that `foo` and `bar` both are having the same `object_id`. Thus changing to the `foo` instance causes same reflection to see through the `bar`.

```
foo = ["a","b","c"]
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]

foo.object_id
#=> 16653048

bar = foo
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]

bar.object_id
#=> 16653048

bar.delete("b")
#=> "b"

puts bar
#a
#c
#=> nil

puts foo
#a
#c
#=> nil
```

See here also that I freeze the `foo` in effect the `bar` also has been frozen.

```
foo.freeze
#=> ["a", "c"]
foo.frozen?
#=> true
bar.frozen?
#=> true
```

Thus the right way is below :

```
bar = foo.dup
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]

foo.object_id
#=> 16450548

bar.object_id
#=> 16765512

bar.delete("b")
#=> "b"

print bar
#["a", "c"]=> nil

print foo
#["a", "b", "c"]=> nil
```

Cheers!!